# Pytorch: How to make sure that all labels are present in each batch

Tags: machine-learning, python, deep-learning, pytorch

How to make sure that each batch will have samples with all the labels? For example, consider sentiment analysis problem with labels positive and negative.

```py
tokens = tokenizer.batch_encode_plus(text.tolist(),max_length = max_seq_len,pad_to_max_length=True,truncation=True, return_token_type_ids=False)    
seq = torch.tensor(tokens['input_ids'])
mask = torch.tensor(tokens['attention_mask'])
y = torch.tensor(labels.tolist())    
data = TensorDataset(seq, mask,y)
data_sampler = RandomSampler(data)
data_dataloader = DataLoader(data, sampler=data_sampler, batch_size=batch_size)
```

I want to have batches like

```
Batch-1 ['positive','positive','positive','negative']
Batch-2 ['negative','negative','positive','negative']
```

where every batch contains all the labels.

Comment: as far as i know, there is no option in pytorch to enforce such policy

Comment: however on average (eg on every epoch) all labels are indeed used

Answer (score 1):

There is [this](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/how-to-enable-the-dataloader-to-sample-from-each-class-with-equal-probability/911) option in PyTorch about stratified sampling.

But if this does not satisfy your needs, my suggestion will be to either do it with [scikit-learn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedShuffleSplit.html) adapting PyTorch code, or to read scikit-learn code and adapt it to PyTorch.